# How can I determine whether a parallel foreach loop is going to have better performance than a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, foreach, parallel-processing

I just did a simple test in .NET Fiddle of sorting 100 random integer arrays of length 1000 and seeing whether doing so with a `Paralell.ForEach` loop is faster than a plain old `foreach` loop.

Here is my code (I put this together fast, so please ignore the repetition and overall bad look of the code)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static int[] RandomArray(int minval, int maxval, int arrsize)
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        int[] rand = Enumerable
            .Repeat(0, arrsize)
            .Select(i => randNum.Next(minval, maxval))
            .ToArray(); 
        return rand;
    }

    public static void SortOneThousandArraysSync()
    {
        var arrs = new List<int[]>(100);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            arrs.Add(RandomArray(Int32.MinValue,Int32.MaxValue,1000));
        Parallel.ForEach(arrs, (arr) =>
        {
            Array.Sort(arr);
        });
    }

    public static void SortOneThousandArraysAsync()
    {
        var arrs = new List<int[]>(100);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            arrs.Add(RandomArray(Int32.MinValue,Int32.MaxValue,1000));
        foreach(var arr in arrs)
        {
            Array.Sort(arr);
        };      
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        SortOneThousandArraysSync();
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("t1 = " + (end - start).ToString());
        start = DateTime.Now;
        SortOneThousandArraysAsync();
        end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("t2 = " + (end - start).ToString());
    }
}
```

and here are the results after hitting Run twice:

```
t1 = 00:00:00.0156244
t2 = 00:00:00.0156243
```

...

```
t1 = 00:00:00.0467854
t2 = 00:00:00.0156246
```

...

So, sometimes it's faster and sometimes it's about the same.

Possible explanations:

- The random arrays were "more unsorted" for the sync one versus the async one in the 2nd test I ran
- It has something to do with the processes running on .NET Fiddle. In the first case the parallel one basically ran like a non-parallel operation because there weren't any threads for my fiddle to take over. (Or something like that)

Thoughts?

Comment: Your methods are named backwards or at least confusing. It's not sync vs. async here. Both methods are synchronous. It's parallel vs. non-parallel. Also use `Stopwatch` to do benchmarks. The system clock (via `DateTime.Now`) only has a precision of about 10ms. Also who knows whether .NET fiddle compiles release or debug? You have to run this on optimized code for it to be worth anything.

Comment: Honestly, in general, you don't know ahead of time. You have a hypothesis and then you test it. Writing performant code requires doing a lot of hypothesis generation via diagnostics and profiling and then testing. And you have to write good tests. The above code fall into some of the common pitfalls when writing benchmarks. You can find many articles describing them. I would advise using something like [NBench](https://github.com/petabridge/NBench) if you want to write microbenchmarks like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `Parallel.ForEach()` if the code within the loop takes a significant amount of time to execute. In this case, it takes more time to create multiple threads, sort the array, and then combine the result onto one thread than it is to simply sort it on a single thread. For example, the `Parallel.ForEach()` in the following code snippet takes less time to execute than the normal ForEach loop:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);

    Parallel.ForEach(numbers, n => Factorial(n));

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        Factorial(number);
    }
}

private static int Factorial(int number)
{
    if (number == 1 || number == 0)
        return 1;

    return number * Factorial(number - 1);
}
```

However, if I change `var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);` to `var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);`, the ForEach loop is faster than `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: You should also consider type of objects in the array. it's good that only int is there, but if there are objects with dynamic type, it will add the cost of boxing-unboxing.

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper Absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

When working with *small tasks* (which don't take a significant amount of time to execute) have a look at [Partitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create(v=vs.110).aspx) class; in your case:

```
public static void SortOneThousandArraysAsyncWithPart() {
  var arrs = new List<int[]>(100);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    arrs.Add(RandomArray(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue, 1000));

  // Let's spread the tasks between threads manually with a help of Partitioner.
  // We don't want task stealing and other optimizations: just split the
  // list between 8 (on my workstation) threads and run them
  Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, 100), part => {
    for (int i = part.Item1; i < part.Item2; ++i)
      Array.Sort(arrs[i]);
  });
}
```

I get the following results (i7 3.2GHz 4 cores HT, .Net 4.6 IA-64) - averaged by 100 runs:

```
0.0081 Async (foreach)
0.0119 Parallel.ForEach
0.0084 Parallel.ForEach + Partitioner
```

as you can see, `foreach` is still on the top, but `Parallel.ForEach + Partitioner` is very close to the winner

Answer (score 0):

Checking performance of algorithms is a tricky business, and performance at small scale can easily be affected by a variety of factors external to your code. Please see [my answer to an almost-duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541097/120955) for an in-depth explanation, plus some links to benchmarking templates that you can adapt to better measure your algorithm's performance.