# Parallel.ForEach and ConcurrentDictionary are slower than regular Dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach, concurrentdictionary

There is a task. The array contains arbitrary strings. We need to count how many times each of the strings occurs in the array. Solve the task in one thread and multithreaded, compare the execution time.

For some reason, the single-threaded version runs faster than the multi-threaded one: 90 ms versus 300 ms. How to fix the multi-threaded version so that it runs faster than the single-threaded one?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ParallelDictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> strs = new List<string>();
            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
            {
                strs.Add("qqq");
            }
            for (int i=0;i< 5000; i++)
            {
                strs.Add("aaa");
            }

            F(strs);
            ParallelF(strs);
        }

        private static void F(List<string> strs)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> freqs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i=0; i<strs.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!freqs.ContainsKey(strs[i]))
                    freqs[strs[i]] = 1;
                else
                    freqs[strs[i]]++;
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("single-threaded {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            foreach (var kvp in freqs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
        }

        private static void ParallelF(List<string> strs)
        {
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> freqs = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            Parallel.ForEach(strs, str =>
            {
                freqs.AddOrUpdate(str, 1, (key, value) => value + 1);
            });
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("multi-threaded {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            foreach (var kvp in freqs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, of course it's slower. Adding an element to a ConcurrentDictionary is _not_ a costly operation. It happens rather quickly. However, for every single element you want to add to it, you dispatch the respective work item `freqs.AddOrUpdate(str, 1, (key, value) => value + 1)` to a background thread. Doingt this comes with an additional performance cost -- and that's what you are seeing: The perf costs of dispatching work items concurrently is dominating compared to the negligble perf cost of the individual work items here.

Comment: Parallelization only makes sense if the concurrently executed work items do _substantial work_ so that the overhead of parallelization can be amortized. The "fix" therefore is: Make your individual work items do more work, much more work than just a simple and quick `freqs.AddOrUpdate(...)`. But with respect to your actual code example, the real fix is to not use parallelization in this particular scenario.

Comment: Also important: You don't do proper perf measurements. It's a complicated topic of how to do it right. Just use Benchmark.NET if you want to measure performance of some code with any degree of confidence.

Comment: An additional source of performance cost in your example code: Since all your work items just add to the ConcurrentDictionary and do nothing else, there will also be a high degree of contention between concurrent work items with respect to placing elements into the ConcurrentDictionary, incurring a further perf penalty.

Comment: Related questions: [Why was the parallel version slower than the sequential version in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418493/why-was-the-parallel-version-slower-than-the-sequential-version-in-this-example) and [Parallel.ForEach slower than normal foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540106/parallel-foreach-slower-than-normal-foreach).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to make the multi-threaded version a little faster than the single-threaded version by using a partitioner to split the data up into chunks that you process separately.

Then each chunk can be processed into a separate non-concurrent dictionary without needing any locking. Finally at the end of each range, you can update a non-concurrent results dictionary (which you would have to lock).

Something like this:

```
private static void ParallelF(List<string> strs)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    object locker = new object();

    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, strs.Count), range => 
    {
        var freqs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; ++i)
        {
            if (!freqs.ContainsKey(strs[i]))
                freqs[strs[i]] = 1;
            else
                freqs[strs[i]]++;
        }

        lock (locker)
        { 
            foreach (var kvp in freqs)
            {
                if (!result.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                {
                    result[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[kvp.Key] += kvp.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("multi-threaded {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    foreach (var kvp in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

On my system that gives the following results (for a release build, .NET 6):

```
single-threaded 50 ms
qqq 1000000
aaa 5000
multi-threaded 26 ms
qqq 1000000
aaa 5000
```

It's only a little faster... if that's worth it is for you to decide.