# How run Async method in ForEach, for each record, and dont wait fo each result

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I would like each record in ForEach run Async. I don't have to wait for each result, so I can just iterate through the list and commission the record executed in the next Thread.
But in the end, I need to return this list with all executed methods.
Does anyone know how I could refactor this example code?

Example:

```
List<SomeObject> CalculateMissingVar(List<SomeObject> records)
{
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        //I woudl like run this method async without wating for each result
        record.PlaceForLongMathEquation = Calculate(5);
    }

    return records;
}

//This method shodul be Async
int Calculate(int number)
{
    return number * number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper error handling omitted for compactness:

```
async Task CalculateMissingVar(List<SomeObject> records)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(records.Select(Calculate));
}

async Task Calculate(SomeObject record)
{
    ...
    record.PlaceForLongMathEquation = x;
}
```

Comment: Does this actually do what was asked? The Calculate() method in the question takes a number as the argument, not the record. Apart from that, Task.WhenAll() is indeed an asynchronous way to solve this.

Comment: @ewerspej I short-circuited the logic since all he did in his example was to assign the result to an instance field.

Comment: I see that and it generally makes sense. I was just curious, because this way the argument is not passed to the Calculate() method anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If each iteration of your loop does not depend on the previous iteration then you can use `Parallel.ForEach`, it sounds like this is exactly what you are looking for (it performs all iterations of the loops asynchronously in parallel with each other according to the number of cores on your server)

You can read about it here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

```
List<SomeObject> CalculateMissingVar(List<SomeObject> records)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(records, record =>
    {
        //I woudl like run this method async without wating for each result
        record.PlaceForLongMathEquation = Calculate(5);
    }

    return records;
}
```

Comment: While the answer fits the question, I would like to point out that Parallel.ForEach() is not running asynchronously. There is a difference between parallelism and the async-await pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099520/async-await-and-parallel-in-c-sharp#14099602

Comment: You are absolutely right, excellent comment!

Comment: Mind that Parallel.ForEach() is a blocking operation in itself.

Comment: Interestingly, I will have a maximum of 50 records to calculate, and operating on a small list of objects, using Parallel.ForEach gives me more time than normal ForEach

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi This is because your list is small, you can see an explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540106/parallel-foreach-slower-than-normal-foreach

Comment: @HaimAbeles here i found also great explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036120/parallel-foreach-slower-than-foreach

When i added extra 50k records i started seeing that Parallel.ForEach is little bit faster.

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi If my answer answered your question, I would appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer